# Is the computation of generated column triggered always when update a row?

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I have a table in MySQL 5.7 with dozens of columns. One of them is a generated column (Stored, not Virtual) which use a large expression to computed the value based on column A, B and C so I guess that MySQL take a little extra time to calculate the value when a new row is inserted or updated.

My simple question is:

Is the computation triggered too when I update other columns (F, G, etc.) on a row?

Can you send me some reference (links) to prove your answer.

Thanks

**Edit:**

I had already read the MySQL [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) suggested by @Barmar:

> STORED: Column values are evaluated and stored when rows are inserted
>   or updated.

As you can see, it said *inserted or **updated*** but I guess that **updated** actually means: *if related columns are updated* because I suppose MySQL is smart enough to do not execute the computation if those columns are not updated. This is actually the assumption I want to confirm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an `update`-statement, MySQL will reevaluate generated stored columns only if a referenced column is specified to be modified (note: not necessarily *changed*, just in the list of columns to modify). You can verify this e.g. with a debug build.

```
create table test (
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  x int, 
  y int, 
  gencolx int as (2*x) stored, 
  gencolconst int as (2) stored
);

insert into test (x, y) values (2, 2);
update test set x = 4;
update test set y = 5;
update test set x = 4;
```

The first `update` will trigger an evaluation of the generated column `gencolx` that depends on `x`:

```
THD::decide_logging_format: info: query: update test set x = 4
update_generated_read_fields: info: field 'gencolx' - skipped
update_generated_read_fields: info: field 'gencolconst' - skipped
update_generated_write_fields: info: field 'gencolx' - updated
update_generated_write_fields: info: field 'gencolconst' - skipped
```

The second `update` does not update a column that is used in any generated column, and thus they are not recalculated:

```
THD::decide_logging_format: info: query: update test set y = 5
update_generated_read_fields: info: field 'gencolx' - skipped
update_generated_read_fields: info: field 'gencolconst' - skipped
update_generated_write_fields: info: field 'gencolx' - skipped
update_generated_write_fields: info: field 'gencolconst' - skipped
```

Unfortunately, MySQL will not check if the value has actually been changed, just if that column is a destination column. So the last `update`, that actually leaves the value of `x` unchanged, will still result in an evaluation of the dependent generated column, because the column `x` is a column to be modified in the `update` statement:

```
THD::decide_logging_format: info: query: update test set x = 4
update_generated_read_fields: info: field 'gencolx' - skipped
update_generated_read_fields: info: field 'gencolconst' - skipped
update_generated_write_fields: info: field 'gencolx' - updated
update_generated_write_fields: info: field 'gencolconst' - skipped
mysql_update: info: 0 records updated
```

The same will by the way happen if you use e.g. `update test set x = x`, which would not change any row.

`update_generated_read_fields` and `update_generated_write_fields` are the relevant functions that evaluate the expression of the generated fields. You can also see that the constant expression for `gencolconst` is not evaluated in updates.

Also unfortunately (and just as a side note), the pure existence of a trigger on that table will result in a second call to `update_generated_write_fields` and a second evaluation of the generated columns if they have been updated the first time - it doesn't matter if it is e.g. an `insert` trigger and you are doing an `update`, the pure existence of any trigger is enough.

Comment: Clear enough for me so I accepted the answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

> - **STORED**: Column values are evaluated and stored when rows are inserted or updated.

This clearly says that the computation is triggered when you update other columns on the row.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I had already read MySQL documentation (I should have put that in the question, sorry) but it's hard to me the belief that MySQL is not smart enough to prevent the computation if no related columns are updated just like it does returning _0 rows affected_ when you update a row with the same values it already have.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that part of your question. My guess is it's smart enough to detect when none of the columns that impact the calculation are being changed, but I don't know how to test it.